# Retrieving values from a checkbox

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I use a php checkbox and I want to retrieve marked values. 
My checkbox code :

```
<label for="cours">Je suis intéressé par un ou plusieurs cours :</label><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="individuel">Individuel<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="semiprive">Semi-privé<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="minigroupe">Mini-groupe<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="intensif">Intensif<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="entreprise">Entreprises<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="distance">A distance<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="telephone">Par téléphone<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="coaching">Coaching<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="soutien">Soutien scolaire<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours" value="diplome">Diplômes officiels<br>
```

php :

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['envoyer']))
  {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
      $cours = stripslashes(trim($_POST['cours']));
    }
  }
?>
```

I want to put it in the variable msg :

```
$msg = 'Cours : '.$cours."\r\n";
```

and sending the message throw the php email function.
But when I do that like this a receive just the first checked choice...
Thank you for your help.
Michaël

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to change the name attribute to cours[] and then php will treat it as an array.

Read up at http://docs.php.net/faq.html

Comment: But know I obtain this : "Cours : Array" when I receive the email...
How can I do to see the values contain in the array?

Comment: +1 for referencing the documentation. -1 for referencing the italian documentation.

Comment: try a <pre><?php print_r($_POST['cours']); ?></pre> and you´ll see all checked options.

Comment: @Gumbo hehehe, didn´t notice the 'it' in the URL, just copied the first result in my google search, but I´ll edit it ^^

Comment: @anddoutoi: print_r() prints shit, it doesn't return a nice string

Comment: Do I have to write : <label for="cours"> or <label for="cours[]">?

Comment: @Michaël: Nae, the label[for] attribute is connected to the input[id] attribute, not the input[name].

Comment: @Charlie: well, you have to treat it as an array ofc. If you want a comma separated string i suggest you use implode/join (http://docs.php.net/implode).

Comment: @anddoutoi: Thank you, I use : $coursListe = implode(', ',$cours); and it returns the list of the elements of the array.

Comment: To be sure that the array is not empty I have done that : 
$count = count($cours);
if($count!=0){
$coursListe = implode(', ',$cours);
}
else{
$coursListe = 'aucun';
}
otherwise I obtain a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Change name to `cours[`*checkbox-value*`]`.

This will make an associative array full over selected checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You may use some thing like this..

```
<label for="cours">Je suis intéressé par un ou plusieurs cours :</label><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[0]" value="individuel">Individuel<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[1]" value="semiprive">Semi-privé<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[2]" value="minigroupe">Mini-groupe<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[3]" value="intensif">Intensif<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[4]" value="entreprise">Entreprises<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[5]" value="distance">A distance<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[6]" value="telephone">Par téléphone<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[7]" value="coaching">Coaching<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[8]" value="soutien">Soutien scolaire<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cours[9]" value="diplome">Diplômes officiels<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Print all checkbox value.

```
<form action="print.php" method="post">

 <input type="checkbox" name="val_list[]" value="value 1">
 <input type="checkbox" name="val_list[]" value="value 2">
 <input type="checkbox" name="val_list[]" value="value 3">
 <input type="checkbox" name="val_list[]" value="value 4">
 <input type="checkbox" name="val_list[]" value="value 5">
 <input type="submit" />

</form>

<?php
      if(!empty($_POST['val_list']))
         {
        foreach($_POST['val_list'] as $data)
             {
                echo $data; 
             }
         }
   ?>
```