# How to GET checkbox values in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving values from a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032456/retrieving-values-from-a-checkbox)

In the following script I am able to return only the last selected value of the checkbox. How do I return the rest of the values for validation purpose.

HTML Form

```
Qualification: <input type="checkbox" name="qual" value="10" /> 10th Std
<input type="checkbox" name="qual" value="12" /> 12th Std
<input type="checkbox" name="qual" value="grad" /> Graduation
```

PHP Code

```
 $qual = array();
 $qual = $_GET['qual'];

 print_r ($qual);
```

Comment: How are the checkbox generated? Hardcoded in HTML? Or do they come from a database or something?

Comment: @SalmanA Handcoded, nothing is coming from DB

Comment: There are soooooo many duplicates of this question on here ...

Answer (score 8):

Try this one .This may help you ....

```
<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="10" /> 10th Std
<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="12" /> 12th Std
<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="grad" /> Graduation
```

PHP Coding:

```
$qualfication = $_GET['qual'];
print_r($qualfication);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the names of checkbox inputs to `qual[]`, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="10" /> 10th Std
<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="12" /> 12th Std
<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="grad" /> Graduation
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `name="qual"` into `name="qual[]"`

This will give you an array:

```
$qual = $_GET['qual'];
print_r($qual);
```