# how to pass array of values of input element with same name in php

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

in javascript m creating these textfeilds

```
<form method="post" action="check.php">
<script>
 var q;
for(q=0;q<3;q++)
{
document.write('<input type="text"  name="ipid" />');
document.write('<br />');
}

<!--and m passing certain values to it :-->


document.getElementsByName('ipid')[0].value="1";
document.getElementsByName('ipid')[1].value="2";
document.getElementsByName('ipid')[2].value="3";
</script>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

how should i retrive values of ipid in php

Comment: You should show some effort. Show what you have tried so far

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032456/retrieving-values-from-a-checkbox

Answer (score 3):

Use an input array - note the `[]` notation:

```
document.write('<input type="text"  name="ipid[]" />');
```

To directly access in Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByName('ipid[]')[0].value="1";
```

On the PHP side your array will be in `$_POST['ipid']`:

```
print_r($_POST['ipid']);
```

PHP will automatically parse the input array into a native PHP array.