# How to access values of checkboxes in php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table with pizza name, pizza type and price. I used a loop to print all the items in a table.

```
<form method="Cart.php" method="post">
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<th>Pizza name</th>
<th>Pizza type</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['subcat_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cat_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['price']. "</td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" value=\"\"   id=\"checkbox\"></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
<input type="submit" name="addToCart" id="addToCart"/>
</form>
```

Now I want to access the pizza names and prices as I click the submit button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of checked checkbox in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291370/how-to-get-value-of-checked-checkbox-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving values from a checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032456/retrieving-values-from-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 2):

You can access them by first checking if it exists...

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox']){
    $checkbox_value = $_POST['checkbox'];
}else{
    $checkbox_value = ""; // set a default value here
}
```

I should add that checkboxes that are NOT "checked" will not pass along in a POST, so you need to explicitly check if it has been "checked" by calling

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){}
```

Which at that point you can decide to set a value yourself or use the value you set in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, Hope this helps.

```
    if(isset($_POST['addToCart'])){

       $check_list = $_POST['checkbox'];

       foreach ($check_list as $checked=>$value) {
          //Here you got all checked values in "$checked"
          //Eg: to move checked values to array
          array_push($pizzaOrdered, $value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the check box will come in as an array if it's just `name='checkbox'` . I think it only works if you set the name like this `name='checkbox[]'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this just use the name of the check box `$_POST['checkbox']`